# Tag for "Is this known?/What field is this?"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

Many times, when I am doing math on my own, I've found some sort of area of math that I want to know more about, if such an area already existed. (This was actually how I found out about percolation theory.) While I do know that such fields may be well above my level of understanding, knowing the right place to look can sometimes be the most helpful step of all towards understanding it; this also helps prevent reinventing the wheel. (Two of the three questions I've asked so far would fall under this category, and I feel that a significant portion of my future questions would do so as well.) Would this be enough to deserve a tag, given that many others are likely in my situation?

Comment: [tag:reference-request] seems appropriate.